# Find row number in column and move data Excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, row

I hope you guys can help me. I have an Excel sheet with data that I want to copy some some values and move them to another column.

The data currently is something like this:

```
A           B
...
20:00:00    2456
21:00:00    2147
22:00:00    5623
23:00:00    1247
00:00:00    3549
01:00:00    1234
...
```

I have data from several days, and when I found the string "00:00:00" which is the beginning of another day, I want to copy the prior 24 values to the next column.

The result should be something like this:

```
A           B       C      D
...
20:00:00    2456
21:00:00    2147
22:00:00    5623
23:00:00    1247
00:00:00            3549
01:00:00            1234
...
22:00:00            2418
23:00:00            3245
00:00:00                   3549
01:00:00                   5437
```

I've started to try found the row number of the values equal to "00:00:00", save them in an array and then make the difference between row value(i+1) "00:00:00" and row value(i) "00:00:00"

Thanks and regards,
Daniel Duarte

Comment: Daniel, do you always have an entry for every hour?  If so, you could do a `For...Next` loop with `Step 24` Then do a `Range.Offset()` to grab the data and cut paste over.

Comment: No, it can be an hour, 15 min, minute or some other frequency. That's why I started to find the 00:00:00 row.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

this has been tested just now:

```
Sub move()
Dim column As Integer
column = 3

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value > Cells(i, 1).Value and Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> "" Then
      Cells(i, column).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
      Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
   Else
      column = column + 1
      Cells(i, column).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
      Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
   End If

Next

End Sub
```

one caveat in this is the case that it is checking if the next hour is less than current, i.e. hour goes back to zero at midnight and it increases the column where it pastes too. It will work for any times within 24 hours window, irrelevant from minutes/seconds

Comment: I've tested your code, it works on finding the first "00:00:00", but the next one is not detected, and only add the collumn at cell "00:00:04". I'll try to work on your code. Thanks a lot btw

Comment: Is it the case that your data is formatted as just time but in fact has date in as well? If so, after it hits 24:00:00 it in fact doesn't reset to 0 and just keeps going. Double check you formatting. My code will NOT work in that case however can be easily changed as it means you can check if the date part is different in the cell value rather than the time part of the cell value.

Comment: Yes, it has in another collumn the date associaced. Probably it is a good way to go. I'll give it a try. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You made a mention of the '24', so I thought it was 24 elements consistently.  Is the timing consistent, or variable?

The solution in VBA is below.

Given something like this:

```
time    value
20:00   100
21:00   200
22:00   300
23:00   400
0:00    500
1:00    600
2:00    700
3:00    800
4:00    900
5:00    1000
6:00    1100
7:00    1200
8:00    1300
9:00    1400
10:00   1500
11:00   1600
12:00   1700
13:00   1800
14:00   1900
15:00   2000
16:00   2100
17:00   2200
18:00   2300
19:00   2400
20:00   2500
21:00   2600
22:00   2700
23:00   2800
0:00    2900
1:00    3000
2:00    3100
3:00    3200
4:00    3300
5:00    3400
6:00    3500
7:00    3600
8:00    3700
9:00    3800
10:00   3900
11:00   4000
12:00   4100
13:00   4200
14:00   4300
15:00   4400
16:00   4500
17:00   4600
18:00   4700
19:00   4800
20:00   4900
21:00   5000
22:00   5100
23:00   5200
```

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Option Explicit
Sub shift()
      Dim Test As String
      Dim NumRows As Integer
      Dim CurrentRow As Integer
      Dim ToCopy As String
      Dim x As Integer
      Dim i As Integer
      ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      ' loop around
      For x = 0 To NumRows - 1
         Range("A2").Offset(x, 0).Select
         Test = ActiveCell.Text
         If Val(Test) = 0 Then
         CurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
            If ((CurrentRow - 24) > 1) Then
                For i = 1 To 24
                        If ((CurrentRow - i - 24) > 0) Then
                            ToCopy = ActiveCell.Offset(-i - 24 + 1, 1).Text
                            ActiveCell.Offset(-i + 1, 2).Value = ToCopy 
                        End If
                Next i
            End If
         Else

         End If


      Next



End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately the frequency of data if variable, so it can be one hour, one minute, 15 minute. Thank you a lot for the quick answer

Comment: No, it won't work, he added in comments that it isn't necessarily on the hour thing.

Comment: I think the best way is to save the row number of all "00:00:00" and then copy the data in between the data from rownumber(i+1)-rownumber(i) to the next collumn.

Comment: danuca9 - yes; a smarter idea; however, this only assumes that the time spacing is consistent.  Great idea!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying this for the arbitrary case; for example, with time differences of 0:15.

This is a bit wordy/pendantic, but gives you the idea.

```
Option Explicit

Sub shift_arb()
      Dim Test As String
      Dim StartRow As Integer
      Dim EndRow As Integer
      Dim NumRows As Integer
      Dim nZeroRows As Integer
      Dim CurrentRow As Integer
      Dim ToCopy As String
      Dim x As Integer
      Dim i As Integer
      ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
      ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
      For x = 0 To NumRows - 1
         Range("A2").Offset(x, 0).Select
         Test = ActiveCell.Text

         ' If we meet the critera; store the row values of the zero rows
         If TimeValue(Test) = "12:00:00 AM" Then
            nZeroRows = nZeroRows + 1
            StartRow = EndRow
            EndRow = ActiveCell.Row

             ' Only do this if you've hit the second zero row
             ' After this, we have to backfill the first, since we don't know the
             ' gap between the zeros
             If (nZeroRows > 1) Then
             ' Go from one zero row to the next

                For i = 0 To (EndRow - StartRow)

                    If ((StartRow - i) > 1) Then
                        ToCopy = Cells(StartRow - i, 2).Text
                        Cells(EndRow - i, 3).Value = ToCopy
                    End If

                Next i

                End If

            End If

        Next x

        ' At the end, cleanup, and do the rest.
        Debug.Print StartRow, EndRow, ActiveCell.Row
        For i = 0 To (EndRow - StartRow)
            If ((i + EndRow - 1) < ActiveCell.Row) Then
                ToCopy = Cells(StartRow + i, 2).Text
                Cells(EndRow + i, 3).Value = ToCopy
            End If
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much asylumax, and sorry for my late reply. I've tested your code, but It don't seem to work correctly.

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if the value of 0:00 is *really* "0:00".   That could be part of the problem.    Perhaps a text compare would be better.   You might check the format, and make sure the data isn't 0:00:01 or something like that.

Comment: yes, it is exactly 00:00:00. This seem to be something easy but I can't get the macro to work.